# JavaScript / Dojo template for JSON

Tags: javascript, dojo, datatemplate, jsontemplate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good Javascript template engine to work with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929111/good-javascript-template-engine-to-work-with-json)

I'm searching for a JavaScript / [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) template to be used with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also [dojox.dtl](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/dtl.html) (not very well maintained ATM) and dojo.replace for doing simple string substitutions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Mustache, which is a standalone template lib. Though it's based on logicless templating.
https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

It has a [Dojo wrapper](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/tree/master/mustache-dojo) as well.