# Link to change div content "<div lang=..."

Tags: html, hyperlink, hide, show

using the script descripted below, i was wondering if there was a way to put a link on the page to allow users to change the displayed language after the page is loaded. Initialy, it displays the default language of the users but i want to allow them to change it if they want dynamicaly.

Thanks!

Thomas

> The usual approach is to keep the languages separate (one HTML file
>   per language for example) and send the content back in the language
>   they want. You could try to parse the Accept-Language header and send
>   back the closest match; you'd probably want to include a language
>   selection widget of some sort as well.
>
> If you really want to do this on the client with JavaScript then you
>   should:

```
Set the lang attribute on each piece of content (or wrapper `s). Grab the language from navigator.language or navigator.userLanguage (check them both, the latter is for IE, the first is, AFAIK, everyone else) and have a suitable default in hand just in case. Then show everything whose lang matches the language and hide everything whose lang doesn't match. For example, if you have this HTML:

<div lang="en" class="wrapper">
    <h1>English</h1>
    <p>Here is some English content.</p> </div> <div lang="fr" class="wrapper" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Française</h1>
    <p>Voici le contenu en français.</p> </div> <div lang="pt" class="wrapper" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Português</h1>
    <p>Aqui você encontra o conteúdo Português.</p> </div> And then some JavaScript (I'll use jQuery as that's my weapon choice)


> $(document).ready(function() {
>     var known = { en: true, fr: true, pt: true };
>     var lang  = (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage || 'en').substr(0, 2);
>     if(!known[lang])
>         lang = 'en';
>     // Find all <div>s with a class of "wrapper" and lang attribute equal to `lang`
>     // and make them visibile.
>     $('div.wrapper[lang='  + lang + ']').show();
>     // Find all <div>s with a class of "wrapper" and lang attribute not equal
>     // to `lang` and make them invisibile.
>     $('div.wrapper[lang!=' + lang + ']').hide(); });
```

Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/hDM3T/2/

> If you keep the show/hide logic in a separate function that takes a
>   language argument then it would be pretty easy to provide a language
>   selection widget of some sort too.
>
> You could also use a class for the language if that's easier to work
>   with using your JavaScript tools but leaving the lang attribute around
>   would be a good idea.

Comment: so you have much overhead for each language and just hide/show the data?

Answer (score 0):

you should be using template engines (you can also use JSON):

http://www.jquery4u.com/javascript/10-javascript-jquery-templates-engines/
[jQuery templating engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170168/jquery-templating-engines)
[What Javascript Template Engines you recommend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788611/what-javascript-template-engines-you-recommend)
http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/
http://microjs.com/#templating
[Good Javascript template engine to work with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929111/good-javascript-template-engine-to-work-with-json)
http://tempojs.com/

but to answer your question, here is the solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function setLanguage(lang) {
     var known = { en: true, fr: true, pt: true };
     if(!known[lang])
         lang = 'en';
     // Find all <div>s with a class of "wrapper" and lang attribute equal to `lang`
     // and make them visibile.
     $('div.wrapper[lang='  + lang + ']').show();
// Find all <div>s with a class of "wrapper" and lang attribute not equal
// to `lang` and make them invisibile.
$('div.wrapper[lang!=' + lang + ']').hide(); 

};
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setLanguage('fr')">fr</a>
```

Comment: Yes that's right Daniel. I want to be able to show/hide content depending on what the user what to use as language but keep only the language used by user when the page is loading.